# Unable to load pdf from document directory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview, nsdocumentdirectory

I have downloaded a pdf from remote server and saved it in document directory. Now I'm trying to retrieve it and display the pdf in the webView but I keep getting this exception:

> failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

before this exception it showing this exception as well:

> objc[8087]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11f29dcc0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11f0b46f0).
>
> One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

But I have noticed that when I try to run from mobile instead of emulator then this second exception is gone. Below is my code for fetching it:

```
    let check:String =  FileNames[0] + ".pdf"
      print("check = \(check)")
 // Method 1
        let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let targetURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent(check)
       
        var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    /*
           // Method 2
       var pdfURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as URL
        pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(check) as URL
        print("check url = \(pdfURL)")
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
        print("check data = \(data)")
        webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"utf-8", baseURL: pdfURL) // pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
      */
        
        //let requestk = NSURLRequest(url: pdfURL as URL)
       // webView.loadRequest(requestk as URLRequest)
        
        
         // Method 3
        
      /*  let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
        
        var pdf = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(check)
        print("check item fetching from documentsUrl = \(pdf)")
        let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
      */
```

I have searched a lot about this exception and followed all the possible solutions but none of it is working. But if I try to display this pdf directly from the remote server's address it is getting displayed. And also I have checked that this pdf is stored correctly. I have tried loading through both webView.loadRequest and webView.load with data method, maybe I'm missing something small.

### Update

```
  var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        print("check final = \(pdfURL)")
        pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(check) as URL
        
        do{
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            var filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(check).path
            let fileManager1 = FileManager.default
            if fileManager1.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                print("FILE AVAILABLE in VC")
              // let fileUrlkk = NSURL(string: filePath)// converting string into URL
                
                filePath = "file://\(filePath)"
                
                let fileUrlkk = Foundation.URL(string: filePath)
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrlkk!)

               //  let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfURL) // tried but didn’t work


                self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())                   
                
            } else {
                print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE in VC")
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("An error took place: \(error)")
        }
```

it displays "FILE AVAILABLE in VC" but still with this exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code to load PDF in WebView

**Swift 3.0**

```
var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent("Swift.pdf") as URL

let data = try! Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

Where pdf file store in Document directory here is the path.

> /Documents/Swift.pdf

**----- UPDATE ------**

1. Create new project.
2. Drag 1 sample PDF in bundle "sample.pdf"
3. And change your controller code with below
4. that's it run

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let check = "Swift.pdf"

    var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    print("check final = \(pdfURL)")
    pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(check) as URL

    if let pdfBundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfBundleURL)

            //Lastly, write your file to the disk.
            try data.write(to: pdfURL, options: .atomicWrite)

        }
        catch {
            // catch errors here
        }
    }

    do{
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        var filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(check).path
        let fileManager1 = FileManager.default
        if fileManager1.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            print("FILE AVAILABLE in VC")
            // let fileUrlkk = NSURL(string: filePath)// converting string into URL

            filePath = "file://\(filePath)"

            let fileUrlkk = Foundation.URL(string: filePath)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrlkk!)

            //  let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfURL) // tried but didn’t work


            self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())

        } else {
            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE in VC")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("An error took place: \(error)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: @shahtajkhalid pdf load or not ?

Comment: nope i didn't get loaded, just blank gray  background appear!

Comment: have you check your file path **pdfURL** , which is coming perfect and pdf is in document directory ?

Comment: yup it is, let me update my code with your changes so you can tell if i'm doing it right.

Comment: check now please!

Comment: hi **pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(check) as URL** what is check ?

Comment: your code work from my side **let check = "Swift.pdf"** i have just added this line. Load pdf in web view...

Comment: i tried but still not working :| how come it is working for you? can you show me how you saved the pdf in document directory? or i'm editing this question check mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148270/discussion-between-shahtaj-khalid-and-ios-dev).

Comment: approve that loading request from Data is the way to make it work with files in Documents directory. Works on simulator without converting to Data though

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
do{
  let directoryURL = try manager.url(for:.documentDirectory,in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)

let docURL = NSURL(string:"XXX.pdf", relativeTo:directoryURL)
    }
catch{print("ERROR")
}
```